# Node.js TCP Client command/response

Tags: asynchronous, node.js, tcp, client

I have a simple server, you send it a command, it replies back with an \r\n delimited response.

So I tried to get a command( callback ) method on my client. Check out this simplified code snippet:

```
var net = require('net');

var Client = function() {
   this.data = "";
   this.stream = net.createConnection(port, host);

   this.stream.on('data', function( data ) {
        var self = this;

        this.data += data;
        self.process()            
   };

   this.process = function() {
       var _terminator = /^([^\r\n]*\r\n)/;

       while( results = _terminator.exec(this.data) ) {
            var line = results[1];
            this.data = this.data.slice(line.length);

            this.emit('response', data);
       };
   };

   this.sendCommand = function( command, callback ) {
       var self = this;

       var handler = function( data ) {
            self.removeListener('response', handler);

            callback && callback(data);
       }

       this.addListener('response', handler);

       this.stream.write(command);
   };

   this.command_1 = function( callback ) {
        this.sendCommand( 'test', callback );
   };

   this.command_2 = function( callback ) {
        this.sendCommand( 'test2', callback );
   };
}
```

So I am doing a client.command_1( function() {} ) and then a client.command_2( function() {}) but in the callback of my command_2 I am getting the response from command_1.

Is this the right way to implement such a thing?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to build?! there are so many nice node modules you could use ... did you take a look at sth like socket.io? it's a great module to do real-time things like chat etc...

Comment: I am aware, but I am trying to get acquainted with building things like this. Socket.io was the first thing that popped to my mind :)

Comment: socket.io is all about having same api for bi-directional communication between *browser* and server. It is wrapper to hide browser differences and different transports awailable to different browsers. If you want server-to-server communication you have much more choice (WebSockets, http, rpc, xmlrpc, your own protocol, message queues - you name it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute

```
client.command_1( function() { 1; } );
client.command_2( function() { 2; } );
```

you add *both* callbacks as 'result' listeners, and when `emit('result')` happens for the first time, both callback are called (then first callback removes itself from a list). You need to set callbacks on some kind of request object, not on a client.

simple code on what happens in your client:

```
var e = new EventEmitter();
e.on('result', function() { console.log(1); });
e.on('result', function() { console.log(2); });
// ...
e.emit('result'); // here we trigger both callbacks which result in printing "1\n2\n"
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case, and I needed some help to get me out of my loop. Thanks :)